# Way to rename object keys to a different format

Tags: javascript, lodash

have an issue with renaming object keys in an easy and smart way.
Have the following object:

```
expanded: false
fontColor: "#123456"
subjectTag: null
title: "Contact us asap"
titleColor: "#654321"
titleSubject: "Call US"
__typename: "alert"
_id: "alertx"
```

to the following format:

```
expanded: false
font_color: "#123456"
subject_tag: null
title: "Contact us asap"
title_color: "#654321"
title_subject: "Call US"
__typename: "alert"
_id: "alertx"
```

The keys are in different formats and I struggled with this.
Also wanted to remove: **__typename** and **_id** keys.

I started to use with lodash **mapKeys** function but got lost:

```
const modifiedObject = mapKeys(objectX, (value, key) => {
   return key + '_';
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to convert camelCase to snake_case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map the keys, and use [`_.snakeCase()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#snakeCase) to convert them to the required format:

```js
const obj = {"expanded":false,"fontColor":"#123456","subjectTag":null,"title":"Contact us asap","titleColor":"#654321","titleSubject":"Call US","__typename":"alert","_id":"alertx"}

const result = _.mapKeys(obj, (v, k) => _.snakeCase(k))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

If you want to avoid converting/remove the keys that start with an underscore (`_`), you can use `k.startsWith('_')` to check it. To avoid converting use a ternary in `_.mapKeys()`, and decide to convert or not by check if the key contains `_`. If you want to remove them, use `_.omit()`.

```js
const obj = {"expanded":false,"fontColor":"#123456","subjectTag":null,"title":"Contact us asap","titleColor":"#654321","titleSubject":"Call US","__typename":"alert","_id":"alertx"}

console.log(_.mapKeys(obj, (v, k) => k.startsWith('_') ? k : _.snakeCase(k)))

console.log(_.mapKeys(_.omitBy(obj, (v, k) => k.startsWith('_')), (v, k) => _.snakeCase(k)))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Great solution, how can I avoid modifying the: "__typename" and "_id" or removing them from the object?

Comment: I was trying to avoid from chaning the keys above to snake_case by using this, but for some reason it returns me only one key: mapKeys(initialValues, (v, k) => {
    k.split(/(?=[A-Z])/)
      .join('_')
      .toLowerCase();
  })

Comment: Your code doesn't work because you don't return the new key, and no return is like returning `undefined`. Remove the curly brackets, or add a `return`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following,

```
const obj = {
  expanded: false,
  fontColor: "#123456",
  subjectTag: null,
  title: "Contact us asap",
  titleColor: "#654321",
  titleSubject: "Call US",
  __typename: "alert",
  _id: "alertx",
}
const arrWithNewKey = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
   if(key === '__typename' || key === '_id') return null; // to remove __typename and _id
   const newKey = key.replace(/([A-Z])/g, (v) => { return '_'+v.toLowerCase(); }); // converting thisKey to this_key
   return {[newKey]: obj[key] };
}).flat();
var newObj = Object.assign({}, ...arrWithNewKey );
```

Comment: It is a good solution and also avoiding snake-case of these properties: _id and __typename, it can be with less and shorter code?

Comment: HI I have updated the code to remove __typename and _id. But I can't think of any shorter code for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` with `Object.keys()`

```js
const obj = {
  expanded: false,
  fontColor: "#123456",
  subjectTag: null,
  title: "Contact us asap",
  titleColor: "#654321",
  titleSubject: "Call US",
  __typename: "alert",
  _id: "alertx",
};

const snakeCase = str => str.replace(/_/g, '').replace(/[A-Z]/g, word => `_${word.toLowerCase()}`);
const transformObj = o => Object.keys(o).reduce((acc, k) => ({...acc, [snakeCase(k)]: o[k] }), {});

console.log(transformObj(obj));
```

Comment: It is a good solution and also avoiding snake-case of these properties: _id and __typename, it can be with less and shorter code?

Comment: @tommyahav10 check my update, I transformed them in two different functions so I can make one line functions and call them independently, this way you can reuse not only for a single time/object. Although it is a little bit shorter, I think loses readability if you are not familiar with arrow functions